# To be "glad of" or "glad about"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I was wondering about the correct usage of the term "glad". It seems to me it can be used (at least) in two different ways: "to be glad of something" or "to be glad about something", indeed I found both of them in some online dictionaries. But I cannot really understand what is the difference (if there is any), or if one of the two is more correct than the other.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To be glad of seems to be synonymous of "being appreciative of something" - this makes me glad, I am glad for you is synonymous with feeling happy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glad of something : - **grateful for something**

glad about something : - **pleased; happy**

[Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/glad)

Comment: As I already commented on this General Reference question

Answer (score 1):

Does it not boil down to the difference in meaning between 'of' and 'about'? The dichotomy raised not only applies to 'glad'. It could equally apply to 'envious','sick', or no doubt countless other adverbs used to qualify the verb 'to be'. In English prepositions are largely determined by usage, and can differ according to place or region. Americans always seem to me to be using the wrong prepositions. E.g. they will say 'different from' (Mike is different from Bill), when surely English English demands that you say 'different to' (Jenny is different to Jane). I would tend to say that I would be 'glad of a cup of tea' meaning I would like one. But I might be 'glad about the fact that tea was available'.

Comment: British English "demands" that it be *different to*. And even than, *different from* is more common than *different to* among speakers of British English. Even worse, from one point of view, is that speakers if BrE are now starting to say *different than*. Heaven help us. [A source](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/different-from-than-or-to).